# How to submit ionic Radio button value on button click?

Tags: ionic-framework, radio-button

Need to pass the value of selected radio button upon clicking the submit button

```
<!--Starts Location Select Popover -->
<ion-list>
  <ion-list-header>
    <h5> Select Location</h5>
  </ion-list-header>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let store of storeLocations">
    <ion-label>{{store?.storeName}}</ion-label>
    <input type="radio" slot="end" value="{{store}}" />
  </ion-item>
  <ion-button expand="block" (click)="dismissLocationSelectPopover(store)">Submit Location
  </ion-button>
</ion-list>
<!--Ends Location Select Popover -->
```

Comment: use `[(ngModel)]="yourVariable"` on input. and pass `yourVariable` to your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[(ngModel)]` is not supported. Better to use `(click)` instead.

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" slot="end" value="{{storeLoc.storeName}}" id="{{storeLoc.storeName}}"(click)="storeSelected(storeLoc)" />
```

**TS**

```
  storeSelected(storeLoc) {
    this.storeSelected = storeLoc;
  }
```